# SQL Merge Replication Triggers Missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, replication, sql-server-2008-r2

In MS SQL Server 2008R2 SP3 Standard, I'm seeing an issue where reinitializing a merge publication with a new snapshot deletes all of the merge triggers from all of the tables, and then when snapshot creation happens does not restore them. At that point the only way to get them back is to run sp_MSaddmergetriggers for every published table. Is there any way around this? Is this a known behavior? I can't seem to find any reference to it in any documentation.